# How do you turn of a crontab in ubuntu 10?

Tags: git, cron, ubuntu-10.04

I "accidently" set a crontab to send me and a couple of other people reminder emails and now I cant turn it of.

I deleted the files from the computer on which I programmed the crontab, but before doing so, I had committed it to a git server and several other students had downloaded it onto their computers as well.

Now, we've tried everything to turn this of but we have failed miserably, even shutting down all the computers (except the server), but nothing has worked.

I would be very happy if you could help. And also, if you could answer whether or not the crontab could work even if its in a git repository on a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo crontab -u [your_user] -e
```

And delete your cron or comment it.

Comment: Check folder `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, what do you have there?